# How to stop surface pro from booting off wrong drive?

Tags: boot, partitioning, live-usb, surface

I'm trying to install ubuntu on my surface and I see that ubuntu is already there after I install it. however, it won't boot without the usb inserted. I've tried reinstalling it and doing some re partitioning and some command lines with no luck. I don't have any other os on the drive, it's blank.